# Flutter push notification does not work when the app is not in the background?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

the Firebase push notifications works perfectly when the app is running or if it's exists in the background but it doesn't work when i am in the app or if the app is terminated from the background, please help!

Here is the notification code:

```
var myToken;
  final fbm =FirebaseMessaging();
  Future<void> showFirebaseNotification() async{
    final fbm = FirebaseMessaging();
    fbm.requestNotificationPermissions();
    fbm.configure(
       onMessage: (msg){
        print(msg);
        return;
      },
      onLaunch: (msg){
        print(msg);
        return;
      },
      onResume: (msg){
        print(msg);
        return;
      }
    );
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    showFirebaseNotification();
    fbm.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      setState(() {
        myToken = token;
      });
      print(myToken);
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Here is what it returns in emulator you can find it in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: use updated version of plugin and refer this official document: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview

Comment: I did update the version but the problem still appear, i will provide it in a picture up below